# Rails 3: Mail::Message cannot be delivered after serializing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, yaml, actionmailer

I want to serialize a `Mail::Message` object in order to store it in the database and send it later.
My first attempt was to use the built-in `serialize` method of ActiveRecord like this:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :mail

  # ...

end
```

Unfortunately, trying to save the record resulted in an exception

```
> foo.save
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mail-2.2.19/lib/mail/message.rb:1714:in `to_yaml'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:55:in `accept'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:36:in `<<'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:165:in `dump'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/base.rb:1720:in `block in arel_attributes_values'
    (...)
```

So I simply created a custom accessor using the `to_yaml` / `from_yaml` functions of `Mail::Message`. But now I experience this strange behaviour:

```
mail_original = UserMailer.user_welcome_email(@user)
=> #<Mail::Message:93415800, Multipart: false, Headers: <From: (...) >, <To: (...) >, <Subject: (...) >, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/plain>>
mail_clone = Mail::Message.from_yaml mail_original.to_yaml
=> #<Mail::Message:92940980, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: (...) >, <From: (...) >, <To: (...) >, <Message-ID: (...) >, <Subject: (...) >, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/plain>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable>>
mail_original.deliver
=> #<Mail::Message:93415800, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: (...) >, <From: (...) >, <To: (...) >, <Message-ID: (...) >, <Subject: (...) >, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/plain>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable>>
mail_clone.deliver
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:546:in `initialize'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:546:in `open'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:546:in `tcp_socket'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:555:in `block in do_start'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:57:in `timeout'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in `timeout'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:555:in `do_start'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:525:in `start'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mail-2.2.19/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:128:in `deliver!'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mail-2.2.19/lib/mail/message.rb:1989:in `do_delivery'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mail-2.2.19/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `deliver'
from (irb):68
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/akrueger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem? Why does serializing the object to yaml make the `Message` object undeliverable? Is there maybe another method to properly serialize the `Message` object to send it later?

Comment: found a solution: adding `ActionMailer::Base.wrap_delivery_behavior mail_clone` ensures that the delivery settings of `mail_clone` are correct. I will post it as an answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I realized the `mail_clone` object did not have proper delivery settings, which caused the failure of the `deliver` call. Browsing through the Rails sourcecode, I found the following solution:

```
mail_clone = Mail::Message.from_yaml mail_original.to_yaml
ActionMailer::Base.wrap_delivery_behavior mail_clone
mail_clone.deliver
```

So this might be a way to serialize the `Mail::Message` object:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  def mail
    @mail_cached || begin
      m = Mail::Message.from_yaml(self.read_attribute :mail)
      ActionMailer::Base.wrap_delivery_behavior m
      m
    rescue
      nil
    end
  end

  def mail=(val)
    @mail_cached = val
    write_attribute :mail, val.to_yaml
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: This helped me to serialize Mail::Message. With just `serialize :mail, Mail::Message` I got errors `TypeError: allocator undefined for Encoding`. I use Rails 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Does specifying the class name help?

```
serialize :mail, 'Mail::Message'
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I had to change it into `serialize :mail, Mail::Message` and set the column default to NULL, but then it just raises the same exception as described first (`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`, in `to_yaml`)

Comment: If I were you (without knowing your business requirements) I would just store the attributes of the mail object as a serialized array, then just build a new mail object when you need to actually send it later.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If nothing else helps, I will probably follow your advice. Nevertheless, I wonder whether there might be a more "railsy" solution.